# Best way to erase on a picture in Swift?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

I'm trying to make an app where I can **erase the background from a picture** that the user imports from *"Camera roll"*. 
So i was thinking of hand drawing a UIColor.clearColor on the UIImage. 
So i tried using Core Graphics to draw on my UIImage.
I tried initially to draw lines by:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        lastPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        var newPoint = touch.locationInView(self)
        lines.append(Line(start: lastPoint, end: newPoint))
        lastPoint = newPoint
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    imageToSend.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
    var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextBeginPath(context)
    for line in lines {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, line.start.x, line.start.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, line.end.x, line.end.y)
    }
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, UIColor.redColor().CGColor) //tried with a red color here
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 80.0)
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, .Round)
}
```

**The problem is that it was very laggy.** The memory usage in *Debug Session* (of xCode) was very high as well as the CPU Usage. 
Running the app on iPhone 6s.
So is there a better way to erase on a picture in Swift? 
Another problem is that it creates lines, I would like it to be more smooth. But that's another problem

Comment: My assumption is the performance lags are caused by frequent calling of *drawRect* method. You are doing really huge work there - render image. Consider getting rid of following: *imageToSend.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)*. Try to comment it out and see if performance become better. If it helps, you can try to overlay UIImageView with image from the gallery with you custom view, which does drawing on top of it. That's an interesting issue, If you shared some sample code, I would played with that.

Comment: @Melifaro Yes it becomes better. So I should put my DrawingView on top of the UIImageView? How can I erase the image then? Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My assumption was the performance lags were caused by frequent calling of **drawRect** method - it does really huge work in your code snippet - render image. The idea was to overlay **UIImageView** containing the image with selection area drawing view, which does the drawing on top of the image view. So it should allow to separate area drawing from image drawing. As a result significantly consuming resources operation (image drawing) should be performed only once.

I have implemented this, you can check out my sample app here:

https://github.com/melifaro-/CutImageSampleApp

[image]

**UPDATE**

That's easy to crop an image once you have bezier path corresponding to your image. You just need:

```
let croppedCGImage =  CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage!, CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path.CGPath));
let croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: croppedCGImage!)
```

I have pushed sample app changes as well. Hope it helps.

Comment: wow! it's perfect. thank you! I'm looking for a way to delete the remaining transparent portion of the image. Now it save all the image out of the "green" line. I want a smaller image

Comment: thank you, I'll try it after. I improved the code to make the line more smoother using _addCurveToPoint_ instead of _line_